# How do I define a new date string for multiple languages and use it in Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, localization, momentjs

I'm successfully [changing languages](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-language/) and using the built-in [Long Date Formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/long-date-formats/) in [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com). While many formats exist, I need a custom format.

**How to do I define and use a new format for multiple languages in Moment.js?**

Here are the formats I wish to use in each language:

```
en: "ddd, MMM D YYYY"
fr: "ddd D MMM YYYY"
ja: "YYYY年M月D日 ddd"
```

I assume usage will be something like this:

```
moment.lang('fr'); // change language globally
myDateString = moment().format('CUSTOM_STRING_HERE'); // format date
```

**Note:** I can place each of these format strings into my language phrase files along with the other strings—this is the solution I'm currently using—but I'd like to know the best way to do this with the Moment.js library.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best you can do is something like this:

```
var format;
switch (moment.lang())
{
    case 'fr':
      format = 'ddd D MMM YYYY';
      break;
    case 'jp':
      format = 'YYYY年M月D日 ddd';
      break;
    case 'en':
    default:
      format = 'ddd, MMM D YYYY';
}
myDateString = moment().format(format);
```